C# Unity Button Holdable and Clickable
I want to make a button that's clickable and holdable, similar to pressing delete once to delete one character but once you hold it it will start deleting multiple. I looked at another post and tried following it but it just doesn't work and immediately starts giving the bomb health or deleting I want to to wait a little then start deleting multiple since otherwise it will delete multiple even if you press once.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

public class GMScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bomb;
    public GameObject explosionPrefab;
    public int bombHealth = 10;
    public TMP_Text bombHealthText;
    public TMP_Text bombHealthNumber;

    public float initialDelay = 10.0f;
    public float repeatingRate = 0.5f;
    public float allowNextKeyboardInput = 0.0f;

    public AudioSource explosion;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        explosion = GetComponent<AudioSource>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 pos = bomb.transform.position; 
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            RemoveHealth();
            allowNextKeyboardInput = Time.time + initialDelay;
        }
        
        else if(Time.time > allowNextKeyboardInput && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Debug.Log(Time.time.ToString());
            Debug.Log(allowNextKeyboardInput.ToString());
            RemoveHealth();   
            allowNextKeyboardInput += repeatingRate;
        }
       
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) == false) 
        { 
            allowNextKeyboardInput = 0f;
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            AddHealth();
            allowNextKeyboardInput = Time.time + initialDelay;
            
        }
        
        else if(Time.time > allowNextKeyboardInput && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            AddHealth();
            allowNextKeyboardInput += repeatingRate;
        }
        
        else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return)) 
        { 
            allowNextKeyboardInput = 0f;
        }

        void RemoveHealth()
        {
            if (bombHealth != 0)
            {
                bombHealth -= 1;
                {
                    UpdateText(bombHealth);
                }
                if (pos.x == 15) 
                {
                    Debug.Log("Bomb has been deleted already");
                }
                if (bombHealth == 0)
                {
                    if (pos.x == 15)
                    {
                     Debug.Log("Bomb has been deleted already");
                    }
                
                    if (pos.x != 15)
                    {
                        explosion.Play(1);
                        DestroyObject(bomb);
                    }    
                }   
            }
        }
        
        void AddHealth()
        {
            bombHealth += 1;
            UpdateText(bombHealth);
        }


        void UpdateText(int txt)
        {
            bombHealthNumber.text = txt.ToString();
        }

        void DestroyObject(GameObject obj)
        {
            Instantiate(explosionPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Vector3 bombNewPostion = new Vector3(15.0f ,0.0f ,0.0f);
            bomb.transform.position = bombNewPostion;
            Debug.Log(obj.name + "Has been deleted");
        }

    }
}


I tried following a unity blog but it didnt work and im not sure why

Sorry if it is a bit hard to read I am still new to coding any tips would be great

You need to use EventTrigger component.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html

@HasnainShaukat not really related to the question no

Looks like this is your issue:
...
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) == false) 
{ 
    allowNextKeyboardInput = 0f;
}

...

else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return)) 
{ 
    allowNextKeyboardInput = 0f;
}

What's going on here:

you begin to hold Esc, for example
your first if block sets the allowNextKeyboardInput value to some time in the future (Time.time + initialDelay), and you suggest it will not change

BUT

after that, your second if block works and Return button is not pressed
because of that, allowNextKeyboardInput is set to 0
In the next frame (next Update call), your current time is already more than allowNextKeyboardInput, as it is 0 and Esc is still pressed, so your logic will be called on every update.


What you can do to fix that depends on your needs:

If you need the option for these two buttons to be held simultaneously - you can use two different variables for every button that will contain the time for the logic call relative to this button. I mean creating allowNextEscInput and allowNextReturnInput instead of single allowNextKeyboardInput.
If you need only one of them to work at the same time, you can break the Update method execution after the required logic is called by adding return statements where it is needed to prevent other parts of the Update to be executed this frame.


Or even simpler instead of (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)) rather just use (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)) which would only run exactly once when the key is released and not have the issue of being true all the time while the key is not pressed (could still have edge cases when both are pressed etc but that's another topic)
